# eigenvalues and eigenvectors of linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

What is going on here? What is A'?

I don't understand what A' is in this text and how they got it:

[image]

I understand how they got the eigenvalues and the eigenspaces. But what is > A' for T relative to the basis B'?

Comment: Do you understand how we can represent a linear transformation as a matrix *with respect to a chosen basis*?

Comment: No I don't.... can you help out with that? my textbook isn't great about this and neither are the class notes.

Answer (score 1):

A linear transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ can be represented as an $m\times n$ matrix if we have a basis $\mathcal{B} = \{u_1, \cdots, u_n \}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n $ and a basis $\mathcal{B'} = \{v_1, \cdots, v_m \}$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

The way this works is we take any vector $w$ in the domain, $\mathbb{R}^n $, and we write it uniquely as a linear combination of basis elements.

$$w = \lambda_1 u_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n u_n $$ (for scalars $\lambda_i$)

Because $T$ is linear we have

$$T(w) = T(\lambda_1 u_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n u_n) = \lambda_1 T(u_1) + \cdots + \lambda_n T(u_n)$$

So, if we know what $T$ does on each basis element $u_i$, we can figure out what $T$ does on *any* vector.

Now $T$ is going to send every basis vector $u_i$ to a vector in the codomain, $\mathbb{R}^m$. So we can decompose each $T(u_i)$ into basis elements in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

$$T(u_i) = a_{i,1}v_1 + \cdots + a_{1,m} v_m$$ (for scalars $a_{i,j}$).

So to fully describe $T$, all we need to know are the $a_{i,j}$s.

But, of course the $a_{i,j}$s depend on the bases we chose. So we say that the matrix where the element in the $i$th row and $j$th column is $a_{i,j}$ is *the matrix of $T$ with respect to (or relative to) the bases $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B'}$*. A good way to remember this is to know that the $j$th column is the coefficients of $T(u_j)$.

If the domain and codomain are the same, oftentimes we choose the same basis $\mathcal{B}$ for both and we just call it the *matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}$.*

The nice thing about representing transformations as matrices is that addition of transformations is the same as addition of matrices, and composition is matrix multiplication.

Now that you know how to find the matrix of a linear transformation with respect to fixed bases, do you see how to answer your question?

Comment: Sorry what is this line:$ T(ui)=ai,1v1+⋯+a1,mvm$

Comment: @KittyCapital $T(u_i)$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$, so we can express it uniquely as a linear combination of the basis vectors $v_1, \cdots , v_m$.